# Is a set with no limit points closed?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

For example, consider the set: $$\{2,\ 3,\ 5\} \subset \mathbb R.$$

This set has no limit points.

A [closed set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed_set) (also [this](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ClosedSet.htm)) is a set which contains all of its limit points.

The set described above contains all of its $0$ limit points, therefore it is closed.

Is this reasoning correct? Can it be made rigorous more other than just re-writing it with quantifiers?

Thank you.

Comment: Yup, that's correct - and perfectly rigorous.

Comment: It does not *not* contain all it's limit points ;)

Comment: Seen in a different way, the set would not be closed if there is a limit point not belonging to it. Since there is no limit point at all, this can't happen. Your argument is perfectly fine.

Comment: Yes.  And no, it can not be made more rigorous.  (Unless you want to prove it has no limit points which ... is always a fun activity (for masochists)... but is not really required).

Comment: Pet Caradonna is winking but... to not be closed means it does not contain all its limit points.  Which means there would have to be a limit point that is not contained in it.  That is not the case as there are no limit points whatsoever.  So it is impossible for it not to be closed.  No winking.  That's irrefutable, isn't it?

Comment: Note: rewriting the proof with quantifiers and a bunch of other notation does not make the proof any more rigorous.  The rigor of a proof refers to the argument, not the notation.  Notation can, however, help with ambiguity.

Comment: There is the concept of "vacuously true".  If definition X means all FOO are condition Y.  And there are no FOO.  The definition X *is* satisfied.  That's it.  That's valid.  You are done.  No more rigor or explanation is required.  Use it, love it.  Don't apologize for it.  (Oh, but when you become a teacher, be gentle when introducing it do others.  Remember the safety phrase is "It is true all of them--- *all zero of them!*".)

Comment: Well this has been enlightening. Thank you everyone!

Comment: @fleablood If I become a teacher, I pray I don't confuse my students ;-;

Comment: Why do you say the set has no limit points?  Consider the sequence $a_n = 1$

Comment: If $S$ is not closed then $S$ has a limit point not belonging to $S$ . $A$ $ fortiori:$ If $S$ is not closed then $S$ has a limit point. The previous sentence is equivalent to: If $S$ has no limit point(s), then $S$ is closed.

Comment: @DougM Many, if not most, texts would not define that as a limit point as the limit is nescessarily equal to the terms of the sequence.  Many, if not most, text define limit points and for all neighborhoods of the point there is an element of the set that is *distinct* from the point.  Or it is a limit of a sequence in where infinitely many of the terms are not equal to the limit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Right, the set is closed, for the exact reason you described.

$$\forall x\in \emptyset: P(x)$$
is vacuously true regardless of $P(x)$. This is perfectly rigorous reasoning (in the context of real analysis).

Comment: Thank you for that. Now I feel less guilty.